# How do taxes work if one's spouse dies?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, marriage, form-1040, death

My question is not for estate planning, but to understand taxes (similar to [question for Canada](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100987)) but when taxes have been filed regularly (and pertaining to the U.S., not Canada).

Suppose a couple has been filing married jointly for many years and with time one of them dies in middle of the year. For **that year** will the surviving spouse will file as Married filling jointly? What about **subsequent years** (assuming that surviving spouse does not re-marry)?

Comment: It looks like the IRS has [a tool to answer this](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/what-is-my-filing-status).

Comment: Note that the tool is a rather longwinded way to find out that yes, if your spouse dies during a tax year, you can still file as married jointly for that year. What counts is that you were married for any part of the tax year.

Comment: @chepner thanks, the IRS tool is longwinded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

married jointly for that year

and subsequently as "head of household" if you still have children to take care of

but confirm from TAX professional.